# jQuery validation plugin: Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-validate

I have a large Rails project with over 80 js files, and I keep getting this message in Chrome's console:

```
Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing.
```

I can't figure out what's throwing that message, though.  All forms that I'm using the validation plugin on seem to correctly validate as they're supposed to.

How can I trace back to see which file or function is actually causing this message to appear?

Here's the relevant part from the validation plugin:

```
  // if nothing is selected, return nothing; can't chain anyway
  if ( !this.length ) {
    if ( options && options.debug && window.console ) {
      console.warn( "Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing." );
    }
    return;
  }
```

It seems that validate() is being called on a non-existing selector, but I call validate() in hundreds of places throughout the project, which is why I'm looking for a way to trace the exact call to the validate() method.

Comment: tried searching for this text in your project?

Comment: It finds it in jquery.validate.min.js, but that would seem to be expected...

Comment: Couldn't possibly know what's going on here without seeing your code.

Comment: I can't possibly paste all the 80+ files of javascript.  That's why I'm asking for help tracing the error...

Comment: You don't need to paste all 80+ JavaScript files if this warning originates from the Validate plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to finally track down the code that was causing the problem.

I edited the jquery.validate.min.js file so that it looked like this:

```
  if ( !this.length ) {
    if ( options && options.debug && window.console ) {
      console.warn(this.selector); //this showed the call to validate() that was the problem
      console.warn( "Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing." );
    }
    return;
  }
```

Looking at the console, I then found the appropriate file, which had this (in CoffeeScript):

```
  $('body.drawing_categories #yield form').validate
    debug: true,
    submitHandler: (form) ->
      add_addl_drawings = $('<input/>').attr(
        type: 'hidden',
        id: 'add_addl_drawings'
        name: 'add_addl_drawings'
      ).appendTo(form)
```

The `debug: true` part was the problem.  Once I took it out, the warning in the console went away.

Much kudos and thanks to Sparky, who led me to this solution.

Comment: Instead of editing the plugin, you could have globally searched your JS for `debug: true`.  For whatever it's worth, you've only turned off the warning message.  The root cause is still there: calling `.validate()` hundreds of times on forms that don't exist in your DOM.  What you can or can't do about that is another matter.

Answer (score 10):

From the jQuery Validate plugin itself...

```
(function($) {
$.extend($.fn, {
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate
    validate: function( options ) {

        // if nothing is selected, return nothing; can't chain anyway
        if ( !this.length ) {
            if ( options && options.debug && window.console ) {
                console.warn( "Nothing selected, can't validate, returning nothing." );
            }
            return;
        }
 ....
```

So it seems something is very wrong with how you're using the plugin.  The code would seem to indicate that you've not properly attached `.validate()` to your `form` element.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"but I call `validate()` in hundreds of places throughout the project, which is why I'm looking for a way to trace the exact call to the `validate()` method."*

Your console errors are only relevant to the page loaded in the browser.  Surely you don't have hundreds of `<form>...</form>` objects loaded on the single page.

---

The console "warning" will only appear if you have `debug:` option set to `true` and it only means that `.validate()` is being called on a form that doesn't exist in the DOM.  It's only a warning, not an error.  Besides, you cannot really use the plugin with `debug:` set to `true` because the form will never submit.

> *"**Enables debug mode**. If true, **the form is not submitted** and certain
>   errors are displayed on the console (will check if a window.console
>   property exists). Try to enable when a form is just submitted instead
>   of validation stopping the submit. Example: **Prevents the form from
>   submitting** and tries to help setting up the validation with **warnings
>   about missing methods** and other debug messages."*

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Agreed.  As I've tried to communicate with the original post, I call validate() many, many times in my project.  So I'm trying to trace and see which call is the problem...

Comment: @croceldon, the console errors are only relevant to the page loaded in the browser.  How many forms are you loading on the one page?

Comment: In most cases, there is just one form, but sometimes two.

Comment: @croceldon, so when the console error/warning appears, it's only relevant to the one or two forms.

Comment: On Rails, all the javascript files are run, so it could be from calling validate() from any file.  I can reload any page on the site, and no matter which forms are showing, I get this warning in the console.

Comment: The warning will only appear if you have `debug: true` set and it only means that you're calling `.validate()` on a form that doesn't exist.  It's only a warning, not an error.  Besides, you cannot really use the plugin with `debug:` left set to `true`.

Comment: You're right.  Once I used `this.selector`, I could find the calling method, and sure enough, it had `debug: true` in it.  Good catch!

Comment: @croceldon, Glad you figured it out.  Could have also searched for `debug: true` as well if you hadn't remembered your selector.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the console and see where the error appears, click on the file where the error is happening.

Set a `breakpoint` to this line and refresh the page. Before you get the error again, look at the **stacktrace** option on the right, and notice how it got to this point, this can help you go backwards in determining where the underlying issue is.

It will show you functions that lead it to where it is. You can also see the "Scope variables", to see if something is undefined / null here where it shouldn't be.